# waiting for xserver to shut down (ee) server terminated successfully (0)?

Tags: 14.04, xorg, vmware

I've downloaded mininet 64bit and I imported it on VMware workstation 12. Installed command startx, but when I install gui "Ubuntu-desktop" or "ubuntu-gnome-desktop" and then run command `startx` i get the following error. I'd appreciate it if you help me out here step by step since I'm a beginner. Tried some methods found on the Internet but none of'em pan out.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what is 'mininet'?

Comment: Perhaps that's it: http://mininet.org/

Comment: @whtyger,Yes Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be alarmed. You have to again type 'startx' to boot normally.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved,solution :

step 1)`sudo apt-get install xinit`

step 2)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

step 3)`sudo reboot`